# What else is in the little room in Picard's Ready Room?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

On the Enterprise-D in *The Next Generation*, the Captain's Ready Room has a little side room that contains a replicator. Picard is often seen going into it to order his "[Tea, Earl Grey, Hot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2IJdfxWtPM)".

[image: Captain Picard ordering his tea.]

As far as I can tell, we only ever see the little room from roughly the angle in the screenshot above. However, there seems to be more space in the compartment than would be necessary for just the replicator, as this design sketch shows:

[image]

The drawing doesn't show anything else in the room, but it's not an official sketch.  (Also notice that the "captain" has hair...)

If the only purpose of the room is to house the replicator, then it would be possible of course to do away with the alcove altogether and have the replicator on a main wall, as in Janeway's Ready Room.

[image: Design sketch of the little tea room.]

This begs the question:

**What is the intended purpose of the extra room? Does it house anything other than the replicator?  Does it have a washroom or wardrobe, etc?**

Comment: I'm thinking since the Enterprise was a diplomatic ship, closing the door kept it hidden and more professional-looking (and the odd shape just caused by where on the ship it was positioned)

Comment: Replicators can make clothes, maybe that room is so he can get changed when he has guests over?

Comment: Perhaps a nice minibar, for when the "ready" room serves as a "done" room.

Comment: Its a portal to narnia

Comment: It contains a hair replacement surgery unit.

Comment: I don't think the drawing from EAS is a *pre-production* sketch rather than a simplified drawing conveying the room layout that we have seen in so many episodes in a non-photorealistic manner. For that matter, the captain is supposed to be a generic Starfleet captain, not necessarily Jean-Luc Picard. Granted, the Stargazer model makes it quite safe to say this is specifically the Enterprise-D ready room (on the other hand, the fact that there is a Constellation class model on display at all is another hint this is *not* a pre-production sketch).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper : I'll change it, but let's not do this all day, shall we?  :-)

Comment: @Praxis: Oh, I didn't realize this answer is by you, too. I normally barely look at who wrote answers on SE before responding (so my perception of their content is not unfairly influenced by my knowledge about the author) ;)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper : Fair enough, and no worries.  :-)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper "Congratulations on your commission, Captain Blonde. Here's the ready room: You got your lionfish, your ancient alien artifact, your model of Jean-Luc Picard's first ship. Stay out of the replicator alcove if you can—it's full of bats."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It doesn't house anything other than the replicator, as you can see from this walkthrough of the ship from the interactive 1994 CD-Rom

As to why the room is there at all, I'd guess that it's simply that it was in the original plans (possibly as a small bathroom?) and Picard just couldn't be bothered to have them do the remodeling.

Comment: Janeway's personal bathroom is through a separate door; http://oehler1990.bplaced.net/blueprints/intrepid_original/sd-intrepid-nx-74600-sheet-9-x.jpg

Comment: Nice finds.  I guess in-universe, Picard's alcove was probably supposed to contain a personal loo, as you say, but I can't find anything to confirm.

Comment: Well, [according to Duke Nukem 3D](https://youtu.be/Qmh8lDAhS7c?t=58s), this is a little imprecise...

Comment: Knowing Picard, I would assume perhaps a small bookshelf and a spare uniform. Ah, well.

Answer (score 9):

The space appears to have been originally intended to be a "head" (navy speak for a ship's toilet) as you can see from these [early designs of the *Enterprise D* floor plan](http://forgottentrek.com/designing-the-next-generation-bridge/) by Andrew Probert.

[image]